# Looping through an array and display only one index of content in a time interval (Angular 2+)

Tags: html, angular, loops, intervals

I am trying to find the best way to loop through an array in Angular 2+ and only display the data of the array every 10 seconds

for example

```
phrase = ["Hello", "Yo", "Whats up?"];

<div *ngFor = "let p of phrase">
 {{p}}
<div>
```

Some interval of time goes by and displays "Hello" then it removes "Hello" and then shows "Yo" and so forth and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're obviously many ways to do this but you can use for example `interval()` from `rxjs`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    {{ phrase[index$ | async] }}
  `,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  phrase = ["Hello", "Yo", "Whats up?"];
  index$: Observable<number>;

  constructor() {
    this.index$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      map((item, index) => index % this.phrase.length),
    )
  }
}
```

This `index$` will every second emit an index telling you which phrase to print with `phrase[index$ | async]`.

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtmdxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

use javascript `setInterval` method instead of `ngfor`

```
phrase = ["Hello", "Yo", "Whats up?"];

constructor(){ 
  this.timeOut();
}

  timeOut(){
     let count = 0;
     setInterval(() => {
       if(count === this.phrase.length ){
         count = 0;
       }
       this.name = this.phrase[count]
       count++
     },1000)
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvhcxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)